# All allowed hosts in settings file not working on Django site on Windows machines

Tags: django

The main allowed host - www.mysite.com is working on all browsers/ios/android/etc. However, mysite.com is not working on any browsers.

It's a Django site and I've added these two allowed hosts into the settings file.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.mysite.com', 'mysite.com']
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which browsers? And does it generate a debug error saying that the host is not allowed on those browsers?

Comment: Sorry I actually checked and it doesn't work on any browsers. I hadn't properly cleared my cache before.

Comment: How do you run Django? It's usually behind some web server software and that might not know about mysite.com.

Comment: The site is live on python anywhere, so I'm running python/django on their development server.

Comment: Are you getting any feedback for logs? If so, please update your answer with them.

Comment: No log errors, as far as I can tell. I get "this site cannot be reached, server IP address could not be found".

Comment: that might cause because your domain did not properly configure

Comment: @Toan with the domain hosting site or with pythonanywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure yet, could you provide the flow you've setup for your domain? has a domain hosting to set domain record to redirect to yourusername.pythonanywhere.com? if you can route to www then it suppose to have `www` record on your domain hosting, just make sure that it also has an `A Record`, `@ - ip address`. That's what I've done to make my website available with and without `www`

Comment: Thanks this info helped me fix it. I added a url redirect.